# contains() in Xcode 7 Beta 5

Tags: contains, swift2

so I'm having a problem with my contains method in beta 5. specifically it says it is unavailable when using this code:

```
class func createSlot(currentCards: [Slot]) -> Slot {
    var currentCardValues:[Int] = []

    for slot in currentCards {
        currentCardValues.append(slot.value)
    }
    var randomNumber:Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(13)))
    while contains(currentCardValues, randomNumber + 1) {
        randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(13)))
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated, not sure if it is a problem with the beta or just my new working with Swift 2, as it works in Xcode 6

Comment: "'contains' is unavailable: call the 'contains()' method on the sequence" ... Read the error message, it, em, *contains* the solution.

Comment: Thank you, yeah I see that now. Sorry just teaching myself how to code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `contains()` is no longer a global method that accepts a sequence as an argument. Instead, the method must be called on the sequence

In your case, you should change `contains(currentCardValues, randomNumber + 1)` to `currentCardValues.contains(randomNumber + 1)`

**Swift 1.x**

```
let myNumbers: [Int] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
let number: Int = 3
let contains: Bool = contains(myNumbers, number) //true
```

**Swift 2.x**

```
let myNumbers: [Int] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
let number: Int = 3
let contains: Bool = myNumbers.contains(number) //true
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That easily cleared it up obviously.