# Error: Extra argument in call

Tags: ios, swift

After using this code from a tutorial that apparently worked before, isn't working now using swift 3 but I'm not sure why.  The error shows on the line: if !contains(uniqueValues, value as T)

```
extension Array {

    func unique<T: Equatable>() -> [T] {
        var uniqueValues = [T]();

        for value in self {
            if !contains(uniqueValues, value as T) {
                uniqueValues.append(value as! T);
            }
        }
        return uniqueValues;
    }

    func first<T>(test:(T) -> Bool) -> T? {
        for value in self {
            if test(value as! T) {
                return value as? T;
            }
        }
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're jumping from Swift 1.2 to Swift 3... that's a huge leap. :) There's many changes, you should read [the updated language guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309).

Comment: That `unique` impliementation is O(N^2), you should see http://stackoverflow.com/a/33553374/3141234

Comment: Another one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32159295/contains-in-xcode-7-beta-5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Swift 2, [`contains(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/sequence/1641180-contains) has been refactored into an instance method on `Array`:

```
if uniqueValues.contains(value as T)
```

Comment: Is it also a protocol extension method of SequenceType for sequences of Equatable elements (http://stackoverflow.com/a/25391725/1187415).

Comment: @MartinR Oh thanks, I linked the wrong function!